# Searching for string anywhere in a cell - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a macro that runs through a list of search words, concatenates them into a string separated by `|`s and then searches a separate sheet for matches. However this macro only finds exact matches (down to the sentence case) and not just if the string appears in the cell. I think I should be using the `FoundCell` function (instead of `If InStr...`) to get the searching I want, but I'm having trouble.

```
Public Sub HighlightListedValues()
    Dim strConcatList As String
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Sheets("List").Range("A1:A13")
        strConcatList = strConcatList & cell.Value & "|"
    Next cell

    For Each cell In Intersect(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange)
        If InStr(strConcatList, cell.Value) > 0 Then       
            cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you referring to [Chip Pearson's FindAll addin](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/FindAllXLA.aspx)?

Comment: If it is just the case causing problems, you could use `If InStr(UCase(strConcatList), UCase(cell.Value)) > 0 Then`

Comment: Thank you, but it's not only the case, the cells I'm searching contain the keyword in the middle of long descriptions, the current macro only finds a match if the cell contains only the exact word from the search list. e.g. if "Apples" is in the list, I want to be able to find cells that contain: "Apples", "I like apples" and "I ate 2 apples for breakfast" etc

Answer (score 0):

If you need to tell whether part of a string matches part of another string, you are going to have to loop through each of the words in the "search words" string (in which case it is better to use an array, if possible):

```
Public Sub HighlightListedValues()
    Dim searchWords() As Variant
    Dim aWord As Variant
    Dim aCell As Range

    searchWords = Sheets("List").Range("A1:A13").Value

    For Each aCell In Intersect(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange)
        For Each aWord In searchWords
            If InStr(UCase(aCell.Value), UCase(aWord)) > 0 Then
                aCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```